# Rearrange boxplot with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data looks as follows:

```
X=cbind(var1=rbinom(100,1,0.26),var2=rbinom(100,1,0.01),
 var3=rbinom(100,1,0.07),var4=rbinom(100,1,0.09),var5=rbinom(100,1,0.004))
```

If I use:

```
X=melt(X)
ggplot(Xaes(x=variable,y=value))+
  geom_boxplot ()
```

I get plot that isn't useful. How do to adjust the code, if I want to do it with `ggplot`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A boxplot is not the best chart to use if your random variables can only take on the values $0$ and $1$. You need a comma in `Xaes`. Melted `X` does not have a variable called `variable`.  Plus some other points. In any case this is more for StackOverflow than CrossValidated.

Try this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

n = 100
X = cbind(var1=rbinom(100,n,0.26), var2=rbinom(100,n,0.01), 
          var3=rbinom(100,n,0.07), var4=rbinom(100,n,0.09), 
          var5=rbinom(100,n,0.004))

Xmelted = melt(X)
ggplot(Xmelted, aes(x=Var2, y=value))+
  geom_boxplot ()
```

to give something like

[image]

Comment: Thanks Henry for your quick reply! When i used melt(dataframe), the return only consists of variable and value. This was my fault. But i need to visulaize a dataframe consisting only of binary variables, as in the example. Which chart is better? -Could you give a code example ?

Comment: It may depend on whether you use `reshape` or `reshape2` (you should have mentioned this in your question).  As for displaying results, you can show how many 1s and 0s there are or what proportion are 1s.

Comment: I use the reshape2 package. So what you suggest is a histogramm? - can you give an example ?